# Conjugacy Class Equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Let $p$ be a prime and let $G$ be a group with $|G|=p^n$. Show that $Z(G)\neq\{e\}$.

The class equation states $|G| = |Z(G)| + |\cl(a_1)|+\cdots+|\cl(a_n)|$ where the $\cl(a_1)$ are distinct conjugacy classes having more than one element (i.e $a_1 \notin Z(G)$). The class equation can also be written as $|G| = |Z(G)|+ [G: C(a_1)]+ \cdots + [G:C(a_n)]|$ for each $(a_i) \in G, [G : C(a_i)]|G|$ Furthermore, if $a_1 \notin Z(G), [G: C(a_i)] >1$ Thus since $|G| =p^n$, each term of the form $[G : C(a_i)]|G|$ in the class equation is divisible by $p$, thus $p|(Z(G)| + [G :C(a_1)] +\cdots+[G:C(a_n)]$ which implies $p \mid |Z(G)|$ Since $Z(G) \leq G$ we know $|Z(G)| \mid |G|$ Therefore we have $p \mid|Z(G)| |p^n$ which implies $|Z(G)| = p^l$ for some positive integer $l$ implying that the center is not trivial.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: is this an okay proof.

Comment: Basically there are two cases, one is $G$ is abelian and another is $G$ is non abelian. In the former case $G = Z(G),$ hence proved. For the later case your proof line is ok.

Comment: IMO this is easier to do just by letting $G$ act on itself via conjugation. Since every nontrivial orbit has order divisible by $p$, you get $$ |Z(G)|\equiv |G|\equiv0\pmod{p} $$ And since $e\in Z(G)$ then it cannot be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ the claim is trivial, because $G$ is cyclic (hence abelian). Let then $n\ge2$. Note that $a_i\in G\setminus Z(G)\Longrightarrow$ $Z(G)\lneq C_G(a_i)\lneq G\Longrightarrow$ $1\lneq |C_G(a_i)|\lneq p^n\Longrightarrow$ $|C_G(a_i)|=p^{\alpha_i}$, where $0\lneq\alpha_i\lneq n$ $\Longrightarrow$ $[G:C_G(a_i)]=p^{\beta_i(:=n-\alpha_i)}$, where $0\lneq\beta_i\lneq n$. By contradiction, let $|Z(G)|=1$. Then the Class Equation reads:
$$p^n=1+\sum_{a_i\in G\setminus Z(G)}[G:C_G(a_i)]=1+\sum_{a_i\in G\setminus Z(G)}p^{\beta_i}$$
So, $p$ divides the LHS and every term in the sum on the RHS, but $p\nmid1$: contradiction.

Comment: This could be simpler.   The index of any subgroup (including a centralizer) always divides the order of $G.$